# ViewPager - ImageView OutOfMemory

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager

My app is getting crashed (throws OutOfMemoryError) when I try to load images in a ViewPager. Here are the details.

All the images are 720*1280 in dimension with 100-150KB in size.

I even tried using Fragments in a Viewpager to load images.. but after sliding one or two images the app gets crashed.

Any pointers on how to resolve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

720*1280*32 = 29491200 bits = 3.52 mb each one in memory.

Checkout this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) :)

Comment: Can you pls tell me what 24 means here?

Comment: ARGB_8888 - Each pixel is stored on 32 bits (4 bytes). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html

Comment: you can use ARGB_4444 to use 2 times less memory, but imagine quality will be low..

Comment: Looks like ARGB_4444 was deprecated because of poor quality.

Comment: yes, Google provided a great tutorial how to avoid OutOfMemory exceptions called Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently. Read this tutorial and download sample. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.. I've uploaded my code in Github https://github.com/petervenkat/TestProject. Can you please check the code and tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Out of memory error means exactly what is stays. The application is trying to allocate to much memory. Android application are (depending on device) allowed to allocate 30-50MB.
The problem with the view pager is that it tries to hold at least 3 pages (current previous and next) to provide fluent UI work.
Bitmap to be displayed needs to uncompressed. So the only thing that matters is the size (pixel number) and color depth.
Usually 3 bitmaps of size you given should be quite easy hold on the device. I suppose that you are trying to process them in some not proper way, or you are missing releasing them from memory. Can't say more not knowing what are you doing with those bitmaps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. I have uploaded my project in github.. Please check it out https://github.com/petervenkat/TestProject

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to create all fragments on start of your activity, and put it all into collection. It also means that you want them all to be kept in memory - so as you noticed - you got the OOM exception.

Comment: Yes I understand your point.. but I'm not sure how to fix this. Can you please point to some tutorial or links that explain this problem?

Comment: Try to create new fragments in the pager adapter not in the onCreate, not hold them in any list. Will work a bit slow probably, but you should be able to avoid the OOM. Later check tutorial from other answers to get how to chache bitmaps in memory (LruCache) to make application work faster.